# Python passing Oracle Cursor as parameter to Oracle Stored procedure

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to passing the Oracle Cursor from python to Oracle Stored Procedure(SP). The requirement is that SP fetch the data and insert the data into the table.
The SP take two parameters- p1 and p2, p1->VARCHAR2 and p2 is sys_refcursor.

Below is the Stored Procedure details:

p2 is sys_refcursor, the data will be in concatenated format (col1|col2|...)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pt1 (p1 IN VARCHAR2,
                             p2 IN sys_refcursor)
IS
    t VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_err_cd       NUMBER;
    v_err_msg      VARCHAR2(32767); 
BEGIN
     LOOP
          fetch p2
          into t;

          INSERT INTO LIBRA.test_2(col1,col2)
          VALUES(p1,t);
          EXIT WHEN p2%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
      rollback;
      v_err_cd  := SQLCODE;
      v_err_msg := v_err_msg || 'SQL Error:' ||     SUBSTR(dbms_utility.format_error_stack() || chr(10)  ||   dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace(),1,300);
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101,'Error Code : ' || v_err_cd || 'Exception :  ' || v_err_msg );
END pt1;
```

### Python Code:

```
srcqry = "select col1 || '|' || col2 from TEST rownum < 2"

oraconn = qz.core.sqldbs.connect(DBContext.getOracleConnectionName()) ##TODO Add a cursor in dbcontext
qzdb = qz.data.qztable_dbapi.QzTableSql(oraconn) 
cur = qzdb.conn.cursor()
result = cur.execute(srcqry)
print "type of result",type(result) # type 'OracleCursor'
lineStr = 'Call1'
cur.callproc("LIBRA.pt1",[linestr,result])
cur.close()
qzdb.conn.close()
```

Getting "DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" in the line 
cur.callproc("LIBRA.pt1",[linestr,result])

Please help!

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: what package are you using qz?

Comment: package used is cx_Oracle

Answer (score 0):

All database object names are UPPERCASE by default in Oracle, even if they're lowercase in your source code. The solution is to change your invocation of `cur.callproc` to use `"LIBRA.PT1"` instead of `"LIBRA.pt1"`.

Best of luck.

Comment: Tried cur.callproc("LIBRA.PKG_TEST.PT1",[linestr,result]) ,still getting the same error.

Comment: The code in your example shows that `PT1` is a stand-alone procedure. Why did you add a package name (`PKG_TEST`) to the call?

Comment: Bob, That's typo error. Call to SP  cur.callproc("LIBRA.PT1",[linestr,result]),still throws the error  - DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number